# how to align tikzpicture and text in a table?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularx

I need to put my tikzpicture and text in the same height. However, I cannot do it. This is my code:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|X| }
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{
 \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}   
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (0,0.1) rectangle (1,0.4);
    \draw [blue,very thick](0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,-0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
    \node at (2,-0.5) {$w/2$};
    \draw [blue,very thick](1,1.5) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=-90];
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,1.5) -- (1,1.3);
    \node at (0.5,1.8) {$R$};
    \draw[very thick,->, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,0.9);
    \node[red] at (-0.2,1.2) {$\delta$};
    \draw[thick,<->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,0.5);
    \node at (4.5,0.25) {$h$};
    \draw[thick,dashed,->](0,0) -- (4.7,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
    \draw[thick,dashed,->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2) node[anchor=south east] {y};
   \end{tikzpicture} \\$h=1$\;\;$R=4.366h$\;\;$w/2=20h$
   \end{tabular}}
& very very long text........
   \end{tabularx}
   \end{table}
```

The table shows like this:[image]
What I want is to place the text at the same height as my picture, I don't want the blank at the top.
Can anyone help me???
Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and complete your code to form a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). We want something we can copy-paste-compile to work with!

Comment: you have aligned the centre of the paragraph with the baseline of the picture, you probably would prefer top aligned or both centre or both bottom.

Answer (score 6):

This solution doesn't require any additional packages. Instead, it modifies the optional argument of `tabular` along the lines suggested in [David Carlisle's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220531/how-to-align-tikzpicture-and-text-in-a-table#comment518235_220531), and makes use of the `baseline` key when setting up the `tikzpicture`. The use of `baseline` is adapted from the TiKZ manual, around page 125.

Corrections required to construct usable MWE before thinking about answering the question:

- complete code with `\documentclass` etc. to create starting example;
- add `tabularx`, `tikz` as needed packages, and `kantlipsum` just for easy long text;
- add required TiKZ library, `patterns`, as LaTeX complained it couldn't compile without it;
- correct code to enable it to compile by putting maths commands inside a maths environment (`\:` needed to be *inside* `$...$` - not outside).

Changes made in answering the question:

- `\begin{tabular}[c]...` says to vertically centre the tabular on the current baseline, which you don't want...

  - `\begin{tabular}[t]...` aligns the top line with the current baseline, which I think is what you want...
- `tikzpicture` has a default alignment set so that the bottom of the picture is aligned with the current baseline, which combines with the `c` alignment of `tabular` to centre the picture with respect to the first line of text on the right... which is not what you want...

  - `baseline` can be used to adjust the alignment of `tikzpicture` e.g. I've used a named node so that that node's baseline will be aligned with the current baseline and, combining this with the `t` option for `tabular`, this aligns that node with the first line of text on the right... which may be closer to what you want...
  - `y` is the named node, with the name being attached to the `y` label on the axis, which seems to be the top-most node in the diagram.

[image: top aligned to y node]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum, tabularx, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|X| }
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(y)]
            \draw[red,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (0,0.1) rectangle (1,0.4);
            \draw [blue,very thick](0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
            \draw[thick,<->] (0,-0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
            \node at (2,-0.5) {$w/2$};
            \draw [blue,very thick](1,1.5) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=-90];
            \draw[thick,<->] (0,1.5) -- (1,1.3);
            \node at (0.5,1.8) {$R$};
            \draw[very thick,->, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,0.9);
            \node[red] at (-0.2,1.2) {$\delta$};
            \draw[thick,<->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,0.5);
            \node at (4.5,0.25) {$h$};
            \draw[thick,dashed,->](0,0) -- (4.7,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
            \draw[thick,dashed,->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2) node (y) [anchor=south east] {y};
          \end{tikzpicture} \\$h=1\;\;R=4.366h\;\;w/2=20h$
        \end{tabular}}
      & \kant[1]\\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

An alternative way to achieve the same result is to use

- `\begin{tabular}[t]...`
- `\begin{tikzpicuter}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)`

If you would prefer the columns to be centred vertically, you could use a vertically centred `\parbox` for the text in the right column.

```
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|X| }
      \hline
      \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[red,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (0,0.1) rectangle (1,0.4);
            \draw [blue,very thick](0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
            \draw[thick,<->] (0,-0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
            \node at (2,-0.5) {$w/2$};
            \draw [blue,very thick](1,1.5) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=-90];
            \draw[thick,<->] (0,1.5) -- (1,1.3);
            \node at (0.5,1.8) {$R$};
            \draw[very thick,->, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,0.9);
            \node[red] at (-0.2,1.2) {$\delta$};
            \draw[thick,<->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,0.5);
            \node at (4.5,0.25) {$h$};
            \draw[thick,dashed,->](0,0) -- (4.7,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
            \draw[thick,dashed,->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2) node [anchor=south east] {y};
          \end{tikzpicture} \\$h=1\;\;R=4.366h\;\;w/2=20h$
        \end{tabular}}
      & \parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\kant[1]}\\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
```

[image: centred columns]

However, I would also strongly recommend taking a look at the `booktabs` package which is designed for typesetting professional-quality tables. In particular, it enhances the spacing and offers more flexible rules. One of the recommendations is to drop vertical rules completely, and to use slightly thicker horizontal rules to start and end the tabular.

[image: tabular with <code>booktabs</code>]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum, tabularx, tikz, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ lX }
      \toprule
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{
        \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
          \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.center)]
            \draw[red,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (0,0.1) rectangle (1,0.4);
            \draw [blue,very thick](0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
            \draw[thick,<->] (0,-0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
            \node at (2,-0.5) {$w/2$};
            \draw [blue,very thick](1,1.5) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=-90];
            \draw[thick,<->] (0,1.5) -- (1,1.3);
            \node at (0.5,1.8) {$R$};
            \draw[very thick,->, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,0.9);
            \node[red] at (-0.2,1.2) {$\delta$};
            \draw[thick,<->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,0.5);
            \node at (4.5,0.25) {$h$};
            \draw[thick,dashed,->](0,0) -- (4.7,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
            \draw[thick,dashed,->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2) node [anchor=south east] {y};
          \end{tikzpicture} \\$h=1\;\;R=4.366h\;\;w/2=20h$
        \end{tabular}}
      & \parbox[c]{\linewidth}{\kant[1]}\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right! I need to complete the code for you to better help me!

Comment: The booktab environment seems more proper for my table, like the explanation for the left figure. Your answer is so good!!!

Comment: @Windy Thanks. When you are ready, please consider accepting an answer (mine or someone else's) by clicking on the greyed-out checkmark at the top left of the relevant answer. This helps others see that your question is answered. Disclaimer: it gains me points. Bonus: you get points, too!

Answer (score 5):

You probably need an `adjustbox` environment with top alignment for your `tabular`.

So, load the [`adjustbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) package and embed your `tabular` in

```
\begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
....
\end{adjustbox}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |l|X| }
\hline
 \multicolumn{1}{c|}{%
 \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
 \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[red,pattern=north east lines, pattern color=red] (0,0.1) rectangle (1,0.4);
    \draw [blue,very thick](0,0) rectangle (4,0.5);
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,-0.2) -- (4,-0.2);
    \node at (2,-0.5) {$w/2$};
    \draw [blue,very thick](1,1.5) arc [radius=1, start angle=0, delta angle=-90];
    \draw[thick,<->] (0,1.5) -- (1,1.3);
    \node at (0.5,1.8) {$R$};
    \draw[very thick,->, red] (0,1.5) -- (0,0.9);
    \node[red] at (-0.2,1.2) {$\delta$};
    \draw[thick,<->] (4.2,0) -- (4.2,0.5);
    \node at (4.5,0.25) {$h$};
    \draw[thick,dashed,->](0,0) -- (4.7,0) node[anchor=north west] {x};
    \draw[thick,dashed,->] (0,0) -- (0,2.2) node[anchor=south east] {y};
   \end{tikzpicture} \\$h=1\;\;R=4.366h\;\;w/2=20h$
 \end{tabular}
 \end{adjustbox}}
& \lipsum[2]\\\hline
   \end{tabularx}
   \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Your solution is quite convenient to adjust the figure!!!:)

Comment: @Windy You're welcome. Remember that the best way to say thanks here is to accept (and upvote) answers that solve your problems. See [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) for more info.